# BigDecimal rounding when not knowing desired scale

Tags: java, rounding, bigdecimal

i know how rounding BigDecimal with the API,
but i actually work witjh a remote API which
sends to me unformated and not rounded BigDecimals.

As examples, the API back-end returns to me

```
3.70000000000000017763568394002504646778106689453125
```

which invites me to do something like

```
myBg.setScale(1,RoudingMode.HALF_EVEN);
```

when API back-end returns to me

```
3.74000000000000017763568394002504646778106689453125
```

it invited me to do something like

```
myBg.setScale(2,RoudingMode.HALF_EVEN);
```

So my question is :
is there a way to guess the adhoc scale/rounding to apply to the BigDecimal
without parse the BigDecimal and counting the numbers of 0 inside the number

```
3.74 --> 0000000000000 <-- 17763568394002504646778106689453125
```

Thanks by advance.

Comment: Wrong approach. Use the rounding you need for your further work and strip trailing zeros when you don't need them.

Comment: Those numbers look like exact representations of `double` values that would normally represent decimal values with smaller numbers of decimal places.  You could convert your input to a `double` then pass the result to `BigDecimal.valueOf`.  That would give you values that correspond to these "shorter" decimals.

Comment: Is your example data true and accurate?

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem Actually, `Double.toString( 3.74d )` is `3.74`. And `Double.toString( 3.7d )` is `3.7`.  See [code run at Ideone.com](https://ideone.com/u3TcC3).

Comment: @BasilBourque I'm not sure whether you think you're disagreeing with me.  The method that I suggested will give OP the BigDecimal objects that they're looking for.